# Why Angular's $http.get service not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble with an example I found on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json) about Angular services, on this specific case $http.get one.

I have a json.php file where I have the next JSON:

```
{
  "bands": [
    {
      "name": "Red hot chilli peppers",
      "year": "2009",
    },
    {
      "name": "Maroon 5",
      "year": "2005",
    },
    {
      "name": "ACDC",
      "year": "2000",
    }

  ]
}
```

And the Angular and HTML code which should iterate over the object and show the data in it, but it's not working:

**JavaScript**

```
 var serviceTestApp = angular.module('myapp3', []);
    serviceTestApp.controller('controller3', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('json.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.myData = response.data.bands;
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myapp3' ng-controller='controller3'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='x in myData'>
      {{x.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I use Angular 1.5.0

Comment: console.log(response.data.bands);  console it what is the output for that??

Comment: What error is returned? handle your error...     `$http.get('json.php').then(function(response) {
       $scope.myData = response.data.bands;
     }, function(error) {
       //Output error to console
       console.log(error);
     );`

Comment: please put a reachable json.php link as jsut json.php will not work here I am not able to debug your problem

Comment: could you please return the json back from php so that the http call is axctually being made or else check the console and paste the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mean not working what exactly do you mean? Do you mean it's successful but doesn't return what you want? In which case you're probably pointing at the wrong thing in the object.
Or does it throw an error?

You should structure it like this:

```
$http.get('json.php').then(function(response){
   // Place a debugger statement here to see if it's successful
   $scope.myData = response.data.bands;
}, function(error) {
   // No breakpoint needed as you'll see the error in the console window
   console.error(error);
});
```

One other reason could be that you don't have the file in the right place. `json.php` means that I'd expect it to be in the same folder as the controller.